# How to animate a page on unload, after new page has preloaded (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, animation, onbeforeunload

I am trying to animate a page out while a new page is loading in. The effect I am going for is similar to the process used on this site http://www.whitefrontier.ch/. I am more of a designer than a developer so I have had no luck with this. Below are the two solutions that I have tried that I think are closest to correct. I realize on that site, they are using fancybox as a preloader. Do i need fancybox to get the desired result?

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('a').animate({right: '250px'},"slow");
  });

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  $('a').animate({right: '250px'},"slow");
});
```

Comment: a very good resource for this problem: http://designhuntr.com/display-animation-while-page-loading-using-jquery/. This shows two different ways to approach your issue.

Comment: `fancy box` is used for showing images slide show.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $.unload() why not use a page pre-loader? This is a common design pattern for web pages that have to load large static assets(like videos or large images). You can setup your page pre-loader like this:

```
//example js
//Show your web page once all the assets are fully loaded
$(window).load(function()
{
  $('#preLoader').hide();  //Or whatever animation you want to remove the preloader
  $('#pageWrapper').show(); //Or whatever animation you want to show the page
 });

<!-- Example HTML -->
<div id="preLoader">
  <h1>Loading.....</h1>
</div>
<div id="pageWrapper" style="display:none;">
  [page content goes here]
</div>
```